# c# How to get substring with more than one of the same characters

Tags: c#, char, substring

I have the following string, with the variable of `s`:

`Room: 501, User: John, Model: XPR500   Serial: JK0192, Condition: Good`

I want to extract the Model, `XPR500` and the Serial, `JK0192`

I was able to get the model with the following code:

```
                int pFrom = s.IndexOf("Model: ") + "Model: ".Length;
                int pTo = s.LastIndexOf(" Serial:");

                String model = s.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
```

But, I am having difficulty getting the serial value. I have attempted this code:

```
                int pFromt = s.IndexOf("Serial: ") + "Serial: ".Length;
                int pToT = s.LastIndexOf(", ");

                string serial = s.Substring(pFromt, pToT - pFromt);
```

but it returns

`JK0192,Condition: Good`

I am having trouble getting it to get everything from Serial: and the next comma.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: So it seems that `,` is a delimiter sometimes, but not always. Why not between `Model: XPR500   Serial: JK0192`? Are those spaces between the model and serial, or another character? Another character may be rendered as a space. It could be a tab getting lost in copy paste too?

Comment: That is just how the data is exported from another source. There will never be a comma between the model and the serial, but there may be more commas before/after both

Comment: Is there always more than one space between them? Are those really spaces?

Comment: It is 3 spaces indeed, not tab

Comment: So can you just split the string on 3 spaces?

Comment: I could yes, but not sure how that will help me get just the serial

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a simple regex:

```
@"Model\:\s([\w\d]*).*Serial\:\s([\w\d]*).*"
```

Here is a full example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"Model\:\s([\w\d]*).*Serial\:\s([\w\d]*).*";
        string input = @"Room: 501, User: John, Model: XPR500   Serial: JK0192, Condition: Good";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of string delimiters. I would use the titles as delimiters. I wouldn't use comma because:

1. Comma is not always a delimiter
2. You will still need to remove the titles

Here is some code you can try. It uses [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_String___System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_) instead of solely searching strings manually and parsing substrings

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = "Room: 501, User: John, Model: XPR500   Serial: JK0192, Condition: Good";
    s = s.Replace(",", ""); // first, remove all the commas
    var delimiters = new string[] { "Room:", "User:", "Model:", "Serial:", "Condition:" };
    // use a function which doesn't assume the order or inclusion of all the delimiters
    model = getValue(s, delimiters, "Model:");
    serial = getValue(s, delimiters, "Serial:");
    Console.WriteLine($"Model = '{model}'");
    Console.WriteLine($"Serial = '{serial}'");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static string getValue(string s, string[] delimiters, string delimiter)
{
    // find the index of the beginning of the rest of the string after your sought title
    var index = s.IndexOf(delimiter) + delimiter.Length;
    // split the rest of the string by all the delimiters, take the first item
    return s.Substring(index).Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First().Trim();
}
```